# Know the "physical" locations of the blocks of a dask array after `.persist()`

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I want to run dask in a distributed environment (HPC cluster style).

After preparing the array, I run the `.persist()` method which should hopefully distribute the array across the cluster.

However, I would like to know, dynamically, where each block is physically located (i. e. in which node). I haven't found the method... have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at: [`client.who_has()`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.who_has) and/or [`client.has_what()`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.has_what)?

Personally, the [data locality](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/locality.html) side helped me.
And this [side](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/manage-computation.html#dask-collections-to-futures) outlines the differences between `compute` and `persist` again.

Maybe it is also possible with [`publish_dataset()`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.publish_dataset), but I do not have experience with the function.

You can easily check at which worker's memory the object is, with:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da

c_ = Client()
a = da.random.random(100000)
f_a = a.persist()
c_.who_has(f_a)
```

| Key | Copies | Workers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ('random_sample-c56488914f65fdea0c70600b46d3cb24', 0) | 1 | tcp://127.0.0.1:53074 |

Comment: I missed the client methods because I was looking at the array interface. However, I still struggled with a last step, but that was easy: `client.who_has(futures_of(a.persist()))` (having it in a single line does not make sense, but that's just for reference). Maybe I am overcomplicating stuff, but that more or less works as I intended.

Comment: Yep, edited with an example (not a single-liner though^^). However, just pointing out, that the `dd.future_of()` is mainly necessary because of the single-liner :)

Comment: I botchered some tests (I did not reassign the `persist()` return, and things were behaving funny). Now I see that you are absolutely correct and I was overcomplicating my attempts. Thanks :D